# Classes Issue in EMNIST Dataset

Tags: python, keras, mnist

So I'm using the dataset from here https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/emnist
namely emnist-letters-train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

When I go through it returns in 27 classes whilst there should only be 26 as it's for alphabets.
I dug in as much as I can but failed to find in labels for these.

Any help could be great.

Answer (score 0):

A guess from my side would be they left one spare class if the sign is not a letter from the given alphabet or e.g. a number. So if the sign cannot be classified, the 27th spare class ("not a letter") will be assigned to it.
Did you already try to feed it some sign which is not a letter and see if it lands in the same class most of the time?

Comment: Dear Umar, did this solve your question ? If yes, please mark as resolved. Thanks!